# Orientdb open plocal database in studio

Tags: orientdb

How can I have orientdb running in embedded mode in a spring boot server and have studio available as to interact with the database and perform ad-hoc-queries 
in the data generated by the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways of using an embedded db:

1. just open it from the physical path, using ODatabaseDocumentTx

   new ODatabaseDocumentTx("plocal:/the/path/to/the/db")

This will just open the db, with no additional services

2. starting a full OrientDB server inside your application, see http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Embedded-Server.html for v 2.2

This second option will also start an HTTP server and will expose Studio